# Why not set automaticaly select tag first option?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, nuxt.js

I have custom template for get user contacts:

```
<div class="row pl-3" v-for="contact in contacts">
  <div class="col-xs-6 mr-2 mb-2">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="contact.contactType">
      <option v-for="item in getContactTypes">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 mb-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Enter contact" v-model="contact.contact">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row pl-3 mt-2">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" @click="addContact">Add Contact</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      getContactTypes: {
        1:"Phone",
        2:"Facebook",
        3:"Instagram",
        4:"Telegram"
      },
      contacts: [{ contactType: '', contact: '' }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addContact () {
      this.contacts.push({ contactType: '', contact: '' })
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my code select first option is not setted automaticaly. How I can set it automaticaly when read select options from array?

Here you can see code result preview:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to set `contactType: 'Phone'` in your method?

Comment: No, I did not try it, but I just tried it and it worked out. Thanks for the answer! @mare96

Comment: Check my answer, you will have problems with your `v-model` so try something like this. @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try something like this:

```
this.contacts.push({ contactType: 'Phone', contact: '' })
```

Comment: `contact[index].contactType` or `contacts[index].contactType` ? @mare96

Comment: `contacts` my mistake.. Is it working? This is because you need maybe to create new array of object for form sending.

Comment: Both options also work in my case. Your versions:  `contacts[index].contactType` and my without index: `contact.contactType` @mare96